# Execute coroutines in pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I want to run all the coroutines from the list in a pool of constant size and would like to ask if this is the right way how to achieve it. Is there any built in solution for this problem? I have not found any.

```
def subprocess_pool(coroutines, pool_size=3):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_finished = asyncio.Event()

    def done(future):
        event_finished.set()

    @asyncio.coroutine 
    def scheduler(coroutines):
        num = len(coroutines)
        finished = 0
        started = 0
        while finished<num:
            if coroutines and (started - finished) < pool_size:
                cor = coroutines.pop(0)
                task = loop.create_task(cor) 
                task.add_done_callback(done)
                started += 1
            else:
                yield from event_finished.wait()
                event_finished.clear()
                finished += 1
        return True

    loop.run_until_complete(scheduler(coroutines))
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

Making a pool of coroutines does not seem to be the way why we invented coroutines. Coroutines are meant to be lightweight, so that they can be created in very large numbers. Rather than limiting the number of coroutines, I think the right way is to limit the number of running coroutines, and

use an `asyncio.Semaphore`

```
async def worker(semaphore, coro):
    async with semaphore:
        await coro()


async def scheduler(corotines):
    tasks = []
    semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(pool_size)
    for coro in corotines:
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(worker(coro))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop.run_until_complete(scheduler(coroutines))
loop.close()
```

check out [this article](https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/how-do-you-limit-memory-usage-with-asyncio.html) for a full example.

Comment: Should pass the semaphore in create_task: ```worker(semaphore, coro)```